# Count words with the same root

Tags: python, mongodb, algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have a WorkBank DB with words for a particular language. For example, Russian. Russian words have different endings due to quantity and cases (Nominative, Accusative, etc.)

So, Student may be:

студент
студента

and whatnot...

There are other languages, like for example English where a verb can have different forms based on its tense (speak, spoke, spoken, etc).
Also, other languages like Italian and French where words may be joined with another one:

hôtel = hotel
l'hôtel = the hotel

anatra = duck
l'anatra = the duck

I would like to store all words in the WorkBank, however, I would like link them to their parent word and to differentiate unique words vs derivated words, so all forms of студент and all forms of "speak" would count only one.

I know this is a very broad subject and I am not asking for a solution. I would really appreciate if someone could point me the right direction or any documentation I could read to start implementing this.

Comment: I strongly suggest splitting words according to the apostrophe  `'`. `l'hôtel` is really two words, `l'` and `hôtel`. Just because there isn't a space between those two words does not make them one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some steps:

1. Find a lemma for every word (to do it you can check `nltk` library documentation, it contains examples).
2. Translate those lemmas into one language (e.g. English) and then group words by this translation.

Comment: Thanks. I have to read a lot, but you pointed out the right direction.